# PSD to bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, themes, psd

I have a downloaded .psd see here : http://webtechdesk.com/boot/theme.png

I want to convert it in bootstrap based responsive html theme, can any body help me out about this. I know and familiar about the grid system and making the skeleton in bootstrap, but main problem is setting the background image in the same. how to do that?

also this psd has a slider shown in header (you can see the image of boys & girls standing side-by-side). In this slider is some rounded from bottom and flat from top how to make that kind of slider?.

I searched some sliders on google but all the result sliders are completely rectangular or square in shape?

Your Help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take already designed webpage which is structured using bootstrap. And then start making/integrating your design requirements within that. It may help you to get started easily. Below I found some of web layouts which looks somewhere similar to your psd.

http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-width-pics/
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/heroic-features/

And to give curve to images (as shown in your psd), you can use below css to the div (which may contain the images). Adjust these values based on you need.

```
   border-top-left-radius: 2em;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include bootstrap, create one empty css file and include after bootstrap. After that start to build your design. You have all elements in bootstrap what you need for that only you need to build template for your website.

If you need to manipulate with some grid, you can add extra classes to your HTML and give that classes style.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 one">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 two">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 three">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

in CSS

```
.one{
border: 1px solid #f00
}
.two{
border: 1px solid #000
}
.three{
border: 1px solid #f88
}
```

That is same with all elements. You are master of your design, Bootstrap only help you with predefined styles. You can add backgrounds, colors, fonts, styles, wathever you whant.

For some extra options you need to write javascript or jQuery to support your design but that is for individuals. You are alone on this and you need to know advanced CSS and some basics of jQuery to create what you whant.

Also for slider you can add some layer mask or to use CSS3 border radius, you need to figureout what is the best and you need to support mobile devices.